# pageslide doesn't close when the screen is wider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the pageslide.js to create responsive menu. it works fine when I manually shrink down the screen size. However, once I turn on the side panel and didn't close it. it would stay there when I drag the screen to wider size and the top menu showed. Unless I refreshed the page, the panel won't disappear.Any one knows how to fix the issue?